# Installing Node Sailsjs package with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, grunt-contrib-watch

I want to install SailsJs using Node Package Manager.

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/getting-started/getting-started.md

I try to install with the below command on terminal -

> sudo npm -g install sails

But it fails with an error -

> npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open
>   '/Users/.../node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/node_modules/gaze/package.json'

Seems like there is some problem with the gaze package.

And I am not sure how to fix this. 
The full error stack is here -

https://gist.github.com/bhagaban/ebf7509c69b52f63aac5#file-failure-with-installing-sailisjs-using-npm

Please help me with a way to fix this.

Comment: Hi there! Which command are you executing?

Comment: @facundofarias - Sorry. Corrected the question now.

Comment: I was ale to run the command on OSX Yosemite, now I run the command `$ sails -v` and I get: `0.10.5`. What happens if you run `sails -v`? Does it show something? Which OS are you using?

Comment: @facundofarias - I use Yosemite Beta 10.10. Actually since the installation fails, sails doesnt get installed. So sails -v says command not found.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with an old version of NPM. Please try `npm i -g npm`, and then try again.

Comment: Doesnt really help. Same error.

Comment: Okay, so let's try with:
`$ brew update
$ brew uninstall node
$ brew install node
$ sudo brew postinstall node # brew error message provided this recommendation; only worked with sudo
$ npm search # returns long list of packages`
That will install again node and npm

Comment: Tried that. Updated brew, node, npm. Same error.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by clearing the NPM Cache. # rm -rf ~/.npm
# npm cache clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sudo npm install -g npm` to update your npm version
and try to `npm cache clean`